# Google Drive API v3 Python how to add parent to file that doesn't have a parent?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

We are trying to move files into folders in Google Drive with the Google Drive API v3 in Python. This is our function for doing that.

```
def moveFiles(file_id, folder_id):
    # Retrieve the existing parents to removed
    file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields='id, parents, name').execute()
    # print(f"{file.get('name')} - {file.get('id')} - {folder_id} - {file.get('parents')}")                      
    if file.get('parents') == None: 
        service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                    addParents=folder_id,
                                    fields='id, parents',).execute()
            
        

    else:
        if len(file.get('parents')) == 1:
            past_parents = file.get('parents')[0]
        else:
            past_parents = ",".join(file.get('parents'))
        fileservice = service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                removeParents = past_parents,
                                addParents=folder_id,
                                fields='id, parents').execute()
```

The problem we're getting is that it's saying that we can't increase the number of parents. It works fine for folders with parents but for folders without parents it gives an error:

> HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/19hmrfcPe37pX9CGh_ZIiIkzmrmhhGJvZddRO8bBRBO8?addParents=1DbiaUPSQYT8p-3Sc_yeH0t2jQF9GY9ig&fields=id%2C+parents&alt=json returned "Increasing the number of parents is not all
> owed". Details: "Increasing the number of parents is not allowed">

How can we add a parent to a file without a parent in Google Drive API v3 in Python?

Comment: the issue is probably that parents is null,  and addparents is crashing on you.   I would check the code for the client library and figure out what addparents is doing.   I cant help much more with python.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. When you mean `It works fine for folders with parents but for folders without parents it gives an error`, are you talking about the file you are trying to move, or the folder that is its parent? Also, can you explain how was this file/folder created? (by default, if a file is not created inside any folder, its parent My Drive).